# Pytorch: How to format data before execution of machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, pytorch

I'm learning how to use pytorch and I was able to get a grasp on the overall process of construction and execution of ML models. However, what I am not able to grasp is how to "format" or "reshape" the data before executing the model. I keep getting errors like:

> RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [1 x 700], m2: [1 x 1] at c:\programdata\miniconda3\conda-bld\pytorch_1524543037166\work\aten\src\th\generic/THTensorMath.c:2033

Or,

> Expected object of type Variable[torch.DoubleTensor] but found type Variable[torch.FloatTensor] for argument #1 ‘mat2’

So, I have a csv file named "train.csv" with attributes called 'x' and 'y' and there are 700 samples in it, I want to perform a simple linear regression on the data, and I parse data from it using pandas, how do I format or reshape the data such that it will execute smoothly? How does pytorch iterate through input data?

The recent code i executed is:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import pandas as pd

class Linear_Reg(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inp_sz, out_sz):    
        super(Linear_Reg, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(inp_sz, out_sz)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.linear(x)
        return out

train = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\hgstr\\Jupyter_Files\\Data_Sets\\linear_regression\\train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\hgstr\\Jupyter_Files\\Data_Sets\\linear_regression\\test.csv')

x_train = torch.Tensor(train['x'])
y_train = torch.Tensor(train['y'])

x_test = torch.Tensor(test['x'])
y_test = torch.Tensor(test['y'])

x_train = torch.Tensor(x_train)
x_train = x_train.view(1,-1)

#================================
input_sz = 1;
output_sz = 1
epochs = 60
learning_rate = 0.001
#================================

model = Linear_Reg(input_sz, output_sz)
crit = nn.MSELoss()
opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), learning_rate)

for e in range(epochs):

    opt.zero_grad()
    out = model(x_train)

    loss = crit(out, y_train)
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()

    print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(e,loss.data[0]))
```

And it gave out the following:

> RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [1 x 700], m2: [1 x 1] at c:\programdata\miniconda3\conda-bld\pytorch_1524543037166\work\aten\src\th\generic/THTensorMath.c:2033

Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, I believe that your data is not correctly formatted. The tensor should be in the form `[700, 2] (batch x data)` and yours is `[1, 700] (data x batch)`. This makes the model 'think' that you are adding only one entry as training with 700 features instead of 700 entries with only 1 feature.

Reshaping the `x_train` variable should make the code work. Just remove the line `x_train = x_train.view(1,-1)`.

Regarding the second error, it can be that after reading the .csv into a variable its type is Double (due to `pd.read_csv`) while in pytorch by default Tensors are created as floats. I think that casting your input data before feeding it to the model should be enough: `model(x_train.float())` or specifying it in the Tensor creation part `x_train = torch.FloatTensor(train['x'])`. Note that you should cast all the Tensors that are not Floats.

edit: This piece of code works for me

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import pandas as pd

class Linear_Reg(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inp_sz, out_sz):
        super(Linear_Reg, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(inp_sz, out_sz)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.linear(x)
        return out


train = pd.read_csv('yourpath')
test = pd.read_csv('yourpath')

x_train = torch.Tensor(train['x']).to(torch.float).view(700, 1)
y_train = torch.Tensor(train['y']).to(torch.float).view(700, 1)

x_test = torch.Tensor(test['x']).to(torch.float).view(300, 1)
y_test = torch.Tensor(test['y']).to(torch.float).view(300, 1)

# ================================
input_sz = 1;
output_sz = 1
epochs = 60
learning_rate = 0.001
# ================================

model = Linear_Reg(input_sz, output_sz)
crit = nn.MSELoss()
opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), learning_rate)

for e in range(epochs):
    opt.zero_grad()
    out = model(x_train)

    loss = crit(out, y_train)
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()

    print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(e, loss.data[0]))
```

Comment: What about y_train? Do we need to make any changes ?

Comment: I do not know what is the shape of `y_train` so I cannot guess the outcome of the first error. For the second you probably need to cast to float. Try to run the code and see what happens.

Comment: the shape is also 700, I mentioned in my question that there are 700 samples of x and y values, I extracted both of them and implemented a 'view' operation to reshape them

Comment: Did you try to change the code with what I commented? If you did so, what is the output?

Comment: I got -> 'torch.dtype' object is not callable

Comment: x_train = torch.Tensor(x_train).to(torch.float())

Comment: ok, the use of the method `to()` is correct, however, you should remove `()` and just leave `.to(torch.float)` as the error says, it is not callable.

Comment: I made the correction and once again am getting a size mismatch errror :(

Comment: can u please add a link to a small example of your data so I can debug it offline?

Comment: I edited my answer with a piece of code that works for me.

Comment: did you try with the dataset i linked? Its still not working for me :(

Comment: I got: invalid argument 2: size '[700 x 1]' is invalid for input with 300 elements at ..\src\TH\THStorage.c:41

Comment: Sorry I had a typo on my code at  `x_test = torch.Tensor(test['x']).to(torch.float).view(700, 1)` It has to be `x_test = torch.Tensor(test['x']).to(torch.float).view(300, 1)` since test data has 300 elements do the same with `y_test`. Also I think you should try to understand deeply the code, that could be easily solved by knowing the data you are working with + what the code is doing.

Comment: try to normalize your data or initialize the weights in a different way. Using data between 0-1 the loss function seems to reduce.